# How to render ZF2 form in view in ZF1 project

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to use ZF2 classes in ZF1 project. I have been following this link: [Use ZF2 in a ZF1 project](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/migration/zf1_zf2_parallel.html). I can use ZF2 classes to create model, table model by inheriting AbstractTableGateway.

I am getting objects on controller. But when I tries to render those form object on view (phtml). It is throwing error, like this:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Form\Form::openTag() in /var/www/myproject/application/modules/tools/views/scripts/tablesample/add.phtml on line 14
```

Here is the view file:

```
<?php
use Zend\Form\Form as Form;
$baseUrl = $this->baseUrl();
$formObject = new Form();
// this is demo  print block of form element
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $baseUrl.'tools/tablesample/add');
$form->prepare();

echo $formObject->openTag($form);
echo $this->formRow($form->get('name'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('gender'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('hobby'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('email'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('birth'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('address'));
echo $this->formRow($form->get('direction'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();

?>
```

I think ZF1 is not detecting ZF2's form helper or there may be any other way to use ZF2 form helper in ZF1 project.

How can I properly render my ZF2 forms in ZF1 application?

I am following this tutorial to create forms: [Zend Framework 2 : Extending Zend\Form to add Select, Multicheckbox, Email,Date, Textarea, and Radio element](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/zend-framework-2-extending-zendform-to-add-select-multicheckbox-emaildate-textarea-and-radio-element/)

I just need to confirm whether I can use ZF2 forms in ZF1 project or not.
If it can be used then please show me the view file for this tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

While I personally can't offer any advise in integrating ZF2 into ZF1; From the ZF2 side of things, the error you are receiving is due to this line :

```
$formObject->openTag($form);
```

You are trying to use the form object `Zend\Form\Form` to render the open tag of the form. Instead you need to be using the form *view helper* (`Zend\Form\View\Helper\Form`) and then pass in the form (`$form`) as an argument.

For example

```
$this->form()->openTag($form);
```

You are actually doing it right for the forms closing tag (which doesn't need any arguments):

```
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
```

Also, I'm unsure of your purpose for `$formObject = new Form()`; there is not need for a new form instance in the code you posted (and you shouldn't really create new instances in the view like this anyway).

The `$this->form()` will be caught by the magic `__call()` of the renderer; which will then check if there is a view helper registered with the service name `form` (returning it when its found).

All the view helpers work in this manor. They are objects that introspect the arguments provided to them and render the appropriate HTML.

With the `$this->form()` for instance, is used to render the form open tags. Another example could be the URL helper (`$this->url('route')`) which would generate a URL form the provided arguments.

I would recommend [reading up on the view helper documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helpers.html) and take a good look at the source code for the already built in view helpers as this will give you a good idea on how they all work.

Comment: Sorry! $formObject->openTag($form); is dubbing code. I also used $this->form()->openTag($form); tag which is the standard one but not working either.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Do you get any errors? Have you used `echo` to ensure the result is printed?  `echo $this->form()->openTag($form);`

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function openTag() on a non-object in /var/www/myproject/application/modules/tools/views/scripts/tablesample/add.phtml on line 15